# Detecting appication's keyboard and mouse events inside a library

Tags: c, macos, events, keyboard, mouse

What I want to achieve:

The target is to make a Mac OS X library - dylib/bundle/framework, that intercepts all mouse and keyboard events of the application that loaded the library. I just want to log these events, not change them. The library needs to have a C API that exposes the logged events' details.

What I have currently made:

I've implemented two ways for detecting the application's mouse and keyboard events from within the library that the application loads:

1. Installing an event handler using Carbon. For some reason using InstallApplicationEventHandler or InstallEventHandler( GetApplicationEventTarget(), ... ) didn't do the trick. It was only possible to catch all non-application events (all events except for those delivered to the target application that loads my library).
2. CGEventTaps: mouse ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161752/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/altermouse/)) and keyboard ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200503003001/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/alterkeys/)) ones. These work, but are system-wide. I want my library to catch only the events delivered to the application that has loaded it.

Does anyone know how to create application-wide keyboard and mouse hooks/taps, not system-wide ones?

Comment: "I just want to log these events" What for?

Comment: It is not a keylogger if it is what you are asking for. I want this library to remember the last pressed key and the last position where the mouse have been clicked at.

Answer (score 0):

Application specific Event Taps can be created using [CGEventTapCreateForPSN](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html). Current application process serial number can be get using 
`ProcessSerialNumber currentProcess;
GetCurrentProcess(&currentProcess);`

Then create and event tap for this PSN.